# A musical response

Tags: knowledge, visual, story, music

<sup>This puzzle is my own creation.</sup>

---

The other day one of my coworkers asked me whether I was up for a challenge. I said sure, so he handed me a piece of paper.

"Find the response that's hidden in this paper. It must be two syllables." he said, and walked off. I looked down at the paper that was in my hand. All it had were two unlabeled measures of music:

[image: The measures of music]

I spent all last night trying to figure out what the response was; in the end, I decided to ask the folks at Puzzling SE for help. Based on the paper, what is the two-syllable response I should give him?

Here's a hint for those who want it:

> Ч + o + 
>  Embodying some point of technique. Performed for artistic merit.

Comment: Do we need to be able to recognize an existing piece from which this excerpt has been taken?

Comment: @ribs2spare Yes. I assume that's possible, what with all the search things they have on the internet, but let me know if I'm wrong. If you want hints, I can add those, too.

Comment: Okay, I have been using the Musipedia search and other similar websites and nothing is coming up. I tried rhythm search and melody search just in case part of the puzzle was correcting an incorrect pitch or rhythm. I think a hint will be necessary to proceed on this one. It's bugging me because the piece does seem familiar but I can't put my finger on it and I've been thinking about it all day.

Comment: @ribs2spare Okay, I'll add a hint when I get a minute to think of one. The puzzle is in the exact correct key and pitch (and time signature), as far as I know. However, those two measures don't show up right next to each other in the actual piece, so if you're not searching each measure individually, you may want to try that.

Comment: I have tried it and am still not finding it. I think the music search technology is still in the works.

Comment: @ribs2spare Okay! Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm working on a hint right now...

Comment: So, the song is from Chopin (russian ch + o + a pin)

Comment: @someoneinexistence Shh! Don't give it all away ;-)! But seriously, you should really use ROT13 in comments like that.

Comment: @someoneinexistence I've created a simple [rot13 Python program](https://github.com/SamMatzko/Rot13), and there are [lots of others](https://github.com/search?q=rot13) like it on GitHub, so you don't necessarily have to use the web (I don't).

Comment: ok thanks :) i haven't been on github except to try to code in 05AB1E.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two-syllable response is

> 10 4!

How is this a "response"? It's one of

> the CB radio 10 codes listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CB_slang)

The musical extract is from one of

> Chopin's studies: the one in c# minor, op.10 no.4. Specifically, bars 2 and 4. Alternatively (since bars 2 and 10 are identical), bars 10 and 4. A big 10 4 to user cap who spotted that.

Comment: Nice! I just checked the sheet music and rot13(one gra vf gur fnzr nf one gjb)

Comment: @cap I've incorporated that idea of yours (credited) in my answer.

Comment: Correct, good job!